# Query to count used amount of bought packet in date range

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a query that returns the ticket_id, the company_id, the ticket create_time the time used to solve that ticket.

```
SELECT `time_accounting`.`ticket_id`, 
       `ticket`.`customer_id`, 
       `ticket`.`title`, 
       `ticket`.`create_time`, 
       SUM(`time_accounting`.`time_unit`) AS `time_done`
FROM   `time_accounting` 
       INNER JOIN `ticket` 
               ON `ticket`.`id` = `time_accounting`.`ticket_id` 
       INNER JOIN `customer_company` 
               ON `customer_company`.`customer_id` = `ticket`.`customer_id` 
GROUP BY `time_accounting`.`ticket_id`
```

I have also a table that stores the phone support minutes bought by the company_id and when they expires.

**Tables:**

[tickets] ticket_id, company_id, time_done, create_time

[time_accounting_bought] packet_id, company_id, amount, starting_time, ending_time

**Expected result**

```
packet_id, company_id, time_used, time_remaining, time_exceeded

NULL | 1 | 20 | 0 | 20 # => company with no bought packets or no packets for the time of that ticket, exceeded 20h
1    | 2 | 10 | 5 | 0  # => with a packet and not used
2    | 3 | 55 | 5 | 5  # => with a packet and exceeded the available time, or a ticket is not included in the packet dates range
```

It does'nt matter if the query returns multiple rows for the same company.

**The problem is** that in the time_accounting_bought i can have range of times that insersects or includes themselves for the same company. eg. I bought 1 year of support (starting 01/2015), i end up finishing it after 3 month and then i buy 3 month of support (starting 04/2015), so the dates can intersect. *The query must be smart enough to understand in which of the active packets at the ticket time there is some unused time and use it before mark the time as exceeded.*

Comment: The general GROUP BY rule says:
If a GROUP BY clause is specified, each column reference in the SELECT list must either identify a grouping column or be the argument of a set function.

Comment: GROUP BY would'nt help because to group by i need a column (the packet_id) and the relation ticket.create_time => packet.id is'nt univocal and depends on used time of the packet as exposed in the question :/

Comment: where are the actual support minutes they have? i don't see that in either table

Comment: Sorry, I missed to write here the "amount" column.

Answer (score 1):

Just about to head off so I'll add more detail tomorrow if you can't make sense of it - I posted some code to another user who was having a similar problem recently with a "stock" system.

```
WITH ordertemp AS (
select ord.dealercode, 
      ord.partcode, 
      ord.orderqty, 
      ord.ordertype,
      -- use rownumber below if you may have duplicates
      RANK() OVER (ORDER BY case ord.ordertype when 'HotLine' then 1 when 'Urgent' then 2 else 3 end, ord.partcode, ord.dealercode) 'StockPriority',
        sto.stockqty 'InitialStock'
    from tblorder ord
    left outer join tblstock sto
    on ord.partcode = sto.partcode )
    SELECT
        Orders.dealercode,
        Orders.partcode,
        CASE    WHEN Backlog.PriorQty > Orders.InitialStock THEN 0
                ELSE Orders.InitialStock - Backlog.PriorQty END 'Stock',
        Orders.orderqty,
        CASE    WHEN Backlog.PriorQty + Orders.OrderQty < Orders.InitialStock THEN Orders.OrderQty 
                WHEN Backlog.PriorQty > Orders.InitialStock THEN 0
                ELSE Orders.InitialStock - Backlog.PriorQty END 'Allocated',
        Orders.ordertype
    FROM 
        ordertemp Orders
        INNER JOIN
        (
        SELECT A.stockpriority, A.partcode, ISNULL(SUM(B.orderqty),0) 'PriorQty'
        from ordertemp A
        LEFT OUTER JOIN ordertemp B
        on A.partcode = B.partcode
        and A.stockpriority > B.stockpriority 
        group by A.stockpriority, A.partcode ) Backlog
        ON Orders.stockpriority = Backlog.stockpriority
    ORDER BY Orders.StockPriority
```

When you get time please confirm database ie sqlserver. Essentially you're looking at a system where you prioritise your support time for each client based on it's expiry date, then take off the support time used in that sequence.

EDIT: similar approach most likely but I'll take a look at your example more then.

Catch ya tomorrow